# Groupby apply makes an unwanted transpose when there is only one group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Pandas has an inconsistent behavior when doing a groupby-apply with one group :

```
(
    pd.DataFrame({'c1': [0, 0, 0],
                  'c2': [1, 2, 3]})
    .groupby('c1')
    .apply(lambda df: df['c2']).shape
)
```

is equal to `(1, 3)`

while

```
(
    pd.DataFrame({'c1': [0, 0, 1],
                  'c2': [1, 2, 3]})
    .groupby('c1')
    .apply(lambda df: df['c2']).shape
)
```

is equal to `(3, )`.

When there only one unique value in the groupby variable, the resulting Serie is transposed from what I expect.

I need a consistent behavior : the number of rows must be kept at 3 no matter the number of groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify `squeeze=True` in the `.groupby(...)` when you are grouping by a column that only has one value, like this:

```
(
    pd.DataFrame({'c1': [0, 0, 0], 
                  'c2': [1, 2, 3]})
    .groupby('c1', squeeze=True)
    .apply(lambda df: df['c2']).shape
)
```

See the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

Comment: It would work for this example but I'm worried about squeezing might create problems in other situations. The squeeze=True is doing one more thing to fix a problem that's added, I'd like a solution that doesn't add a problem (the transpose) at all.

Comment: What other specific situations are you talking about? Maybe add them to your question and they can be discussed.

Comment: I don't see one. I guess it's fine. Thanks !

Comment: I'm in similar situation to the OP and getting a warning adding *squeeze* parameter: squeeze parameter is deprecated and will be removed. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

The [`squeeze` option was deprecated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32380) in Pandas 1.1.0 and removed in version 2.

The [new recipe for this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32380#issuecomment-1659496578) is

```py
df.groupby(...).apply(...).squeeze()
```